# losing functions when using recompose component as ref

Tags: javascript, reactjs, recompose

I have this simple component

```
class App extends React.Component {
  a = () => null
  b = () => null
  c = () => null

  render() {
    return (<div>hey123</div>)
  }
}
```

and this is my 2nd component with ref to the first one

```
class BApp extends React.Component {
  setComponentRef = ref => {
    console.log('ref', ref)
    this.playerComponentRef = ref
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <App ref={this.setComponentRef} />
      </div>)
  }  
}
```

in this case in the console.log I will receive all App component's functions (a, b, c)
but if I'll use `Recompose.withState` on `App` component I will not receive them anymore. see example here 
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/qYjpoE?editors=1111

to see the working way swtich

```
<ModifyedApp ref={this.setComponentRef} />
```

to

```
<App ref={this.setComponentRef} />
```

what am I missing here ? why the use of Recompose HOC is removing the `App` class component inner functions ?

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass a function `providerRef` to your component and then provide the App instance to it like

```
class BApp extends React.Component {
  setComponentRef = ref => {
    console.log('ref', ref)
    this.playerComponentRef = ref
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <App providerRef={this.setComponentRef} />
      </div>)
  }  
}


class App extends React.Component {
  a = () => null
  b = () => null
  c = () => null
  componentDidMount() {
     this.props.providerRef(this);
  }
  render() {
    return (<div>hey123</div>)
  }
}
```

In case of Recompose, its an HOC and hence the ref will be applied on the HOC and not the inner component, some libraries provide a `withRef` hook to access the innerComponent ref using `this.playerComponentRef.getWrappedInstance()`, however I am not sure about its availability in `recompose`.

Answer (score 0):

HOC will create one new component outside children one. So if you are wrapping subcomponent in HOC and trying to receive ref of wrapped component you will get **HOCs ref**.

There is a workaround here - just pass a ref from the parent component to children in the hoc - just proxy the ref.

Comment: thanks for the reply, "pass a ref from the parent component to children in the hoc" can you show an example please ?