# Material UI's withTheme() hides component from ref prop

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

For the rare times when you need a reference to another JSX element in React, you can use the `ref` prop, like this:

```
class Widget extends React.PureComponent {
  example() {
    // do something
  }
  render() {
...

<Widget ref={r => this.mywidget = r}/>
<OtherWidget onClick={e => this.mywidget.example()}/>
```

Here, the `Widget` instance is stored in `this.mywidget` for later use, and the `example()` function can be called on it.

In Material UI, you can [wrap components around a `withTheme()` call](https://material-ui-next.com/customization/themes/#withtheme-component-component) to make the theme accessible in their props:

```
export default withTheme()(Widget);
```

However if this is done, the `ref` receives an instance of `WithTheme` rather than `Widget`.  This means the `example()` function is no longer accessible.

Is there some way to use `ref` with a component wrapped by `withTheme()` so that the underlying object can still be accessed, in the same manner as if `withTheme()` had not been used?

Here is an example demonstrating the issue.  Lines 27 and 28 can be commented/uncommented to see that things only fail when the `withTheme()` call is added.

[image: Edit Material demo]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to get the ref of the component which is wrapped with withStyles, you can create a wrapper around Widget, and use that with `withStyles` like

```
const WithRefWidget = ({ innerRef, ...rest }) => {
  console.log(innerRef);
  return <Widget ref={innerRef} {...rest} />;
};
const MyWidget = withTheme()(WithRefWidget);

class Demo extends React.PureComponent {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.mywidget = null;
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <MyWidget
          innerRef={r => {
            console.log(r);
            this.mywidget = r;
          }}
        />
        <Button
          onClick={e => {
            e.preventDefault();
            console.log(this.mywidget);
          }}
          variant="raised"
        >
          Click
        </Button>
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}
```

Have a look at this answer to see an other alternative approach

[losing functions when using recompose component as ref](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50151848/losing-functions-when-using-recompose-component-as-ref/50152184#50152184)

[image: Working Demo]

Answer (score 0):

This is a shorter alternative based on Shubham Khatri's answer.  That answer works when you can't alter the inner component, this example is a bit shorter when you can modify the inner component.

Essentially `ref` doesn't get passed through `withTheme()` so you have to use a prop with a different name, and implement `ref` functionality on it yourself:

```
class Widget extends React.PureComponent {
  constructor(props) {
    props.ref2(this); // duplicate 'ref' functionality for the 'ref2' prop
...
const MyWidget = withTheme()(Widget);
...
<MyWidget
  ref2={r => {
    console.log(r);
    this.mywidget = r;
  }}
/>
```